# Access Table ,setting in design ,column 'Catagory' as Combobox in lookup with list "Action";"War";"Drama". in vb.net DGV and Detail how to multiselct

Tags: database-design, display

Acces table column name CATAGORY. In design view lookup i set combobox with list Action,Drama,War.
Now when I run this in vb.net to display as DGV and Detail of Database is good.Each movie can be selected one type,My problem is how can I make selection af (Action War) for one i mean multi selection.
I already tried from ribbon modifylookup as setup in table but this is good only for table,when display in Detail or DGV it shows there only Ac or Dr Or Wa not even for single collection
Someone can help me i appriciate in advance.
Thanks

I tried modify lookup in ribbon of Access, as a part of table it works good as i wish,like when I want to select War And Action for one its both items display in one line good enough.
Now other part is when i use this table in vb.net program.In a form i diplay the table both way Detail and DGV
here is problem

1. Already selected items from table are not showing here, it display only Ac Or Wa
2. It is not showing two items, only one, say Ac or Dr (in Access table column is right Action,War - Action,Drama)
3. I want it this way whn I will add from combobox list I can choose one or two from list
   Please help me not big deal for you guys, for me is big big headache.
   Thanks
   Kamran